# Mongodb : Query based on time in ISODate format

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, date, momentjs

Suppose the sample documents in Mongodb database are as follows:

```
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-09T05:58:19.474Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2014-10-25T07:30:00.241Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-30T15:24:00.251Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2012-01-10T18:36:00.101Z") }
```

Expected:

```
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-09T05:58:19.474Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2014-10-25T07:30:00.241Z") }
```

Iam interested in finding the documents whose time in "date" field is between 04:00 and 08:00 irrespective of day,month and year. Indirectly query has to match any "YYYY-MM-DDT" in date field.

My approach would be, query all the documents within presumed duration of dates from node and then for each document that matched the query, compare the "date" field of document with "yyyy-MM-DDT"+"required_time" ("YYYY-MM-DD is copied from each document's "date field" to compare by converting into moment() and get month,date and year") using moment.js module.

Is there any way to query to directly get the same results?

Note: I am using nodejs to connect to mongodb

Comment: How about to create a time field where you store time in a format like 0800 for 8:00 and query db with {$gt:0400, $lt:0800}. I quess this would be the quickiest way to get your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use the [**aggregation framework**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/), in particular the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** operator which strips the document stream of content based on values within the document and its sub-documents. Depending on the result of a boolean expression, a document can be pruned from the stream, be included in the stream after its sub-documents have also been checked, or just passed complete into the stream. The idea behind **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** is to make the removal of sensitive information from the stream easy.

In your case, the criteria expression uses the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator and the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#exp._S_and)** boolean operator to express the logical AND between the time ranges with the comparison operators **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/#exp._S_gt)** and **[`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/#exp._S_lt)**. Use the **[`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour)** date operator to return the hour for the `date` field as a number between 0 and 23. Thus your final aggregation looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { 
                    "$and": [
                        { "$gt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 4] },
                        { "$lt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 8] }
                    ]                 
                },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }        
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56404450472fe25cc6b85886"),
            "date" : ISODate("2015-11-09T05:58:19.474Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56404450472fe25cc6b85887"),
            "date" : ISODate("2014-10-25T07:30:00.241Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Coud you explain this part "$gt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 4]" in the query?

Comment: Since you are  interested in finding the documents whose time in `"date"` field is between 04:00 and 08:00 irrespective of day,month and year, the expression `"$gt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 4]"` will query the documents where the hour part of the `date` field is greater than 4. This is equivalent to say `getHour(date) > 4`.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose if it is desired to consider minutes as well, say documents between 04:00 and 07:45,then how do we modify the query?

Comment: Looks like [Mongodb : Query based on time in ISODate format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603864/mongodb-query-based-on-time-in-isodate-format) is solved isn't it? As for the "next" problem, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Comment: what's wrong with this query.   db.collection.find({"$and": [{ "date" : { "$gt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 4]}}, {"date" :{ "$lt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 8]}} ]}) . This query is not yielding any result. @chridam

Comment: @helloworld Can you please create a new question for this?

Comment: yeah iam creating new question@chridam

Comment: @helloworld Thanks. In general, the [**`$hour`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) operator is only applied in the aggregation pipeline, not the `find()` query. So in your aggregation your pipeline has two steps, the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) which creates a new field that holds the hour part and the next stage [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) which then queries the documents.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666398/mongodb-query-based-on-time-in-isodate-format-whats-wrong-in-my-query] created new question @chridam

Comment: @helloworld Cheers, I've made my attempt to address this, based on the above fact.