# Mongodb : Query based on time in ISODate format. What's wrong in my query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, date

Suppose the sample documents in Mongodb database are as follows:

```
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-09T05:58:19.474Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2014-10-25T07:30:00.241Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-30T15:24:00.251Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2012-01-10T18:36:00.101Z") }
```

Expected:

```
 { "date" : ISODate("2015-11-09T05:58:19.474Z") }
 { "date" : ISODate("2014-10-25T07:30:00.241Z") }
```

I tried  the following query:

```
 collection.find({"$and": [{ "date" : { "$gt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 4] } }, 
                           {"date" :{ "$lt": [ {"$hour": "$date"}, 8] } } 
                 ]});
```

This query is not yielding any results. Where as the accepted answer in [Mongodb : Query based on time in ISODate format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603864/mongodb-query-based-on-time-in-isodate-format) does. Where I am wrong?

Note: I am using nodejs to connect to mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not yielding any results because the [**`$hour`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) operator is only applied in the aggregation pipeline, not the `find()` query. So in your aggregation your pipeline has two steps, the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) which creates a new field that holds the hour part and the next stage [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) which then queries the documents.

Thus your final aggregation operation will be like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$project": {
            "hour": { "$hour": "$date" },
            "date": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "hour": { "$gt": 4,  "$lt": 8}
        }
    }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```